# Module's source changes don't take effect

Tags: python, module

I am having an issue with python which  looks really weird to me. My script starts to be quite big and is suposed to run a test suite for a program.
My inclusion tree is:

```
run.py --> Module --> Section --> Test
```

The weird behavior I am having is that when I add a modification to my `Module`, `Section` or `Test` module's source file, they don't take effect at all.

I am developing with emacs in my terminal and simply run my script using:

```
python run.py
```

I tried:

1. Restarting the term
2. Restarting the computer (after a few days, it wasn't a bad idea anyway)
3. Cleaning the *.pyc files

The version of my python is `2.5.2` and I am working under a Debian Lenny in VirtualBox.

And I haven't been able to reproduce this behavior on another smaller program to observe it better.

Comment: are you certain that you cleaned ALL .pyc files on your system ?

Comment: @AdrienPlisson I cleaned all the .pyc files in my project tree only. Moreover, my PYTHONPATH only points there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have at least one other module with the same name as one of yours in your PYTHONPATH. Either look for old copies you left around or try changing your module names and see what happens.

You'd see a similar effect if you forgot to reload your modules before running them after you modified them, but restarting your Python session would obviously cause all your modules to be loaded afresh at the first import of each.

Comment: Well, thank you ! That was it. So silly that I didn't see this before. I started working on a shared volume between my Win/Lin VMs and forgot to adapt the python path.